# maxItemCount property not working for JdbcPagingItemReader

Tags: spring-batch

I am setting the maxItemCount property of JdbcPagingItemReader.

I am setting it to 200 but I am getting read/processed/written of 203, 205.

Most of the time I am getting 200 but I get around 200+ commonly.

Why is this happening??

I've checked and there are no same timestamp value for the the sortkey in the 203-205 processed and the max.item.count field is not present in the batch_execution_context  entry in the database table.

There is a JdbcPagingItemReader.read.count.max field but it is set to 200.

I am using oracle.

```
<bean id="batchReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
        <property name="queryProvider">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
                <property name="selectClause" value="select *" />
                <property name="fromClause" value="from TRANSACTION" />
                <property name="whereClause" value="where STATUS = 'OK' and TYPE = 200 " />
                <property name="sortKey" value="TRANSACTION_TIMESTAMP"/>

            </bean>
        </property>
        <!-- Inject via the ExecutionContext in rangePartitioner -->
        <property name="parameterValues">
            <map>

            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="maxItemCount" value="200"/>
        <property name="pageSize" value="50"/>
        <property name="rowMapper">
            <bean class="com.mappers.TransactionMapper" scope="step"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: please share the reader xml configuration

Comment: it should not be possible to get more items, how do you determine the wrong item count?

Comment: The read count exceeds 200, the write count exceeds 200 from the BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION table statistics.

Comment: did you use re-start? afaik the values are not resetted

Comment: no restarts are happening

Comment: Would this happen if the sortKey is non unique. something like timestamp?@MichaelPralow

Comment: Should I file  JIRA for this issue?

Comment: If you check `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT`, is there a "read.count.max" value in there for the steps where the count exceeds 200?